# Sending Email is Not Working When it Hosted to server?

Tags: asp.net, email, email-attachments

Im working with email sending App.It works perfect in Local System(My system). When i hosted it into server it show me the error like "**The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required**".

Here is My Code:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
        ("Mymail@gmail.com", "Mypwd");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(Msg);
```

Comment: Is port 587 opened? You may try to use port 25

Comment: @DouglasThomas how to check whether a port is opened or not?

Comment: You need to ask the hosting provider whether the port 587 open or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false
```

to

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

**EDIT**

Also try to make

```
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
```

**Note**: This is what I have already working mail client on the server